# STL and Dijkstra's algorithm optimization

Tags: c++, graph, stl, time-limit-exceeded

[This is the problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/SHPATH/) and my solution to this is:

```
#include "iostream"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "algorithm"
#include "math.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "time.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#define MALLOC(name,type,n) (name=(type*)malloc(sizeof(type)*(n)))
using namespace std;
typedef unsigned long long int ll;
#include <cstdio>
#define gc getchar_unlocked
const ll INF=~0;
```

Fast input and output:

```
void scanint(int &x)
{
    register int c = gc();
    x = 0;
    int m=0;
    if(c=='-')
        m=1;
    for(;(c<48 || c>57);c = gc());
    for(;c>47 && c<58;c = gc()) {x = (x<<1) + (x<<3) + c - 48;}
    if(m==1)
        x*=-1;
}
void scanstring(string& str)
{
    str.clear();
    str.reserve(20);
    char x;
    while((x=getchar_unlocked())!=EOF&&x!='\n'&&x!=' ')
        str.push_back(x);
}
```

I'm hashing the names for that specific vertex.

The simple hash function:

```
int hash(const string &x)
{
    int y=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i){
        y+=x[i]*137;
    }
    return y%1000;
}
```

`V` - total number of vertices

`u`, `v`, `c`  -source, destination, cost

```
int V,u,v,c,e;  
string name;
typedef pair<int ,int> ii;
typedef std::vector<int> vi;
typedef std::vector<ii> vii;
std::vector<vii> graph;
typedef pair<string,int> si;
vector<vector<si> > h_table;
vi sourced;
vector< vector<ll> > dijkstra_data;
```

Gets vertex position from name:

```
int get_index(const string &s)
{
    int h=hash(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < h_table[h].size(); ++i){
        if(h_table[h][i].first==s)
        {
            return h_table[h][i].second;
        }
    }
}

void dijkstra(int,int);



int main()
{
    //freopen("input","r",stdin);
    int tc;
    cin>>tc;
    while(tc--)
    {
        scanint(V);
        h_table.clear();
        h_table.assign(1000,vector<si>());
        graph.clear();
        graph.assign(V+1,vii());
        sourced.clear();
        sourced.assign(V+1,0);
        dijkstra_data.clear();
        dijkstra_data.assign(V+1,std::vector<ll> ());

        // dijkstra_data stores all shortest paths from a source that have been calculated till now


        for (int i = 1; i < V+1; ++i){
            scanstring(name);
            si x(name,i);
            h_table[hash(name)].push_back(x);
            scanint(e);
            while(e--)
            {
                scanint(v);scanint(c);
                graph[i].push_back(ii(v,c));
            }
        }
        int cases;
        scanint(cases);
        string src,dest;
        while(cases--)
        {
            scanstring(src);
            scanstring(dest);
            int isrc=get_index(src),idest=get_index(dest);
            if(sourced[isrc])
                printf("%llu\n", dijkstra_data[isrc][idest]);
            else
                dijkstra(isrc,idest);

        }

    }

    return 0;
}


void dijkstra(int src,int dest)
{
    vi visited(V+1,0);
std::vector<ll> dist(V+1,INF);
    dist[src]=0;
    typedef pair<int,ll> il;
    typedef std::vector<il> vil;
    std::priority_queue<il,vil,greater<il> > pq;
    pq.push(il(src,0));
    int n=1;
    while(n<V&&!pq.empty())
    {
        il x=pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        int sv=x.first; ll sd=x.second;
        if(visited[sv])
            continue;
        visited[sv]=1;n++;dist[sv]=sd;
        for (int i = 0; i < graph[sv].size(); ++i){
            ll d1=sd+graph[sv][i].second;
            ll d2=dist[graph[sv][i].first];
            if(d1<d2)
            {
                dist[graph[sv][i].first]=d1;
                pq.push(il(graph[sv][i].first,d1));
            }
        }
    }
    dijkstra_data[src].assign(dist.begin(),dist.end());
    sourced[src]=1;
    printf("%llu\n", dist[dest]);
}
```

and TLE is my result.

I know I could use my own heap instead of STL `std::priority_queue`.  I'm new to the STL so I want to know if there is anything associated with STL where I have caused more overhead.

Comment: Note: `for(;(c<48 || c>57);c = gc());` is an endless loop should `c` equal EOF.

Comment: All those STL `#include`s should use `<>`, not `""`.  You also use `<stdio.h>`, `printf`, and `malloc`, which indicate C code instead of C++ code.

Comment: Note: `int hash(const string &x)` returns values -999 to 999.  I suspect this is a problem for `h_table[h]`.

Comment: @chux NO,int hash(const string &x) will only return betwen 0-999 as x[i] is always positive and since only maximum 10 chars of x are there so,it fits in integer range

Comment: @chux  'for(;(c<48 || c>57);c = gc());' that is fast integer so anything within integral values will be taken

Comment: @Jamal c++ codes can use all c libraries and functions of C language by including those libraries. I have submitted lots of codes like this and everything went right

Comment: Yes, it won't cause immediate problems, but `"string.h"` would only be needed if that happens to be your own defined header in the same directory.  If you're just using `std::string`, then only `<string>` is needed.  More information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename?rq=1).  Unless you have a necessary reason for these extra headers, your code will just look less like C++.

Comment: @user2058841 (x[0] + x[1] ... x[9])*137 can well exceed 32767.  `int` is not guaranteed to have a range greater than -32767 to 32767.  Thus the comment about values -999 to 999.

Comment: @user2058841 if `gc()` returns EOF, in `for(;(c<48 || c>57);c = gc());`, the `for` loop does not exit.  Instead the loop repeats.  `c` on the next call will get set to EOF again and again.

Comment: @chux thnx I'm wrong there

Answer (score 4):

You're putting too much effort into your input reading. Just use `cin` it'll be fast enough. The problem is in your algorithm, not the input parsing. The note about input size on the site is meant for languages where naive handling of input can be slow, e.g. Java. C++ is not affected by this.

Instead of implementing your own hash function you can use [`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) (since C++11). Or simply use [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) which is basically a hash map, and save yourself a lot of trouble.

Your naming of types and variables is absolutely horrific. Use descriptive names, a type called `ii` is not descriptive.

[Macros are evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041453/why-are-preprocessor-macros-evil-and-what-are-the-alternatives) don't use them like that.

Now to the core of your problem. You're applying Dijkstra's algorithm for each of the queries in the test case. This is where your slow down is.

You need to use the [Floyd-Warshall Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm). This will bring down your run-time and make you get past the TLE with flying colours.

Answer (score 3):

In your hash function, you're doing `x.size()` in a loop, which will slow the function down quite a lot for a long string. Instead, store the size in a variable and compare to that

```
int hash(const string &x)
{
    int y=0;
    int xLength = x.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < xLength; ++i){
        y+=x[i]*137;
    }
    return y%1000;
}
```

Also, you're `using namespace::std`. [Don't do that, for good reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). As well as this, if you're having to explain your variable names that last for a while and actually require explanation (I'm looking at `V`, `u`, `v`, `c`), maybe name them something else? Or at least include comments if they're the convention that people would expect that would give someone who doesn't know the convention a chance.

Comment: Calling `std::string::size()` is constant time, see here: [std::basic_string::size()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size). To be constant size it's either implemented as an internal `size` member in the string or as a pointer arithmetic with start and end pointers. Both should be inlined by the compiler. This has a negligible effect on the run-time.